# How to return the value of a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary

I have recursive function which walk nested dict and return needed key's value:

```
def recurs(l):
    for key in l.keys():
        if key == '_events':
            return l[key]
        else:
            recurs(l[key])

c=recurs(d)
print c
```

And how i can get these values?

Comment: Right now its return None, but dict have two lists, and then i try to use yield its return empty iter object

Comment: It does not make sense (logically) to return a (one) value from the function as it calls `recurs` potentially several times. So the question is, what kind of return value do you expect? A single value? A list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to get a flattened iterator is to write a generator function:

```
def recurs(l):
    for key in l.keys():
        if key == '_events':
            yield l[key]
        else:
            for x in recurs(l[key]):
                yield x
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `return` it:

```
def recurs(l):
    for key in l.keys():
        if key == '_events':
            return l[key]
        else:
            return recurs(l[key])
```

Comment: That will terminate the loop after the first iteration. Although I don't understand what the loop is for...

Comment: and instead of two lists of values ​​I get one

Comment: @Felix I suppose OP need single value.

Comment: @Roman: But which one? Why do you think he wants the *first*?